# Partial object deserialization from JSON

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a JSON that looks similar to this:

```
{
  "definition": [
    {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "type": "xxx",
          "prop1": 0,
          "prop2": 1
        },
        {
          "type": "yyy",
          "a": 0,
          "b": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My model looks like that:

```
class Configuration {
  public Definition[] Definition {get; set;}
}

class Definition {
  public Input[] Inputs {get; set;}
}

class Input {
  [JsonConverter(typeof(ControlTypeConverter))]
  public InputType Type {get; set;}
  public IDictionary<string, object> Properties {get; set;}
}
```

When I deserialise input using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configuration>(input)`, where `input` is an above-mentioned string, I get what I want but `Properties` property is always `null`.

What I'd like to get is that all unmapped properties for objects from `input.definition[].inputs[]` get squized into `Properties` property, just as if I used `.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>`.

Is there a any better way than writing custom converter for `Input`?

Comment: `I get what I want`, that's not feasible according to your `json` above. It's invalid `json` and fails all RFC's, what should we do?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Which RFC's exactly? Putting it through a JSON validator shows that there is 1 comma too many, which I guess is a leftover from copy and pasting. **Edit after OPs edit:** Now there is not error in the JSON

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with it. Anyway - reformatted

Comment: The problem is that the `prop1`, `prop2`, `a`... properties aren't inside an array with the name `properties`. If they were this would work. Do you have control over the JSON source? If not, I'm afraid a custom converter will be the only option

Comment: @MindSwipe yeah, I know there are not there but that's not the point. I want them to be represented inside my model as such. How to get that without writing custom converter? In instead of `Input[] Inputs` I had `JObject[] Inputs` this is exactly what I'd get except then I won't have `Type` property. So.... this way or another - not ideal ;)

Comment: @MindSwipe specifically it *was* 8259, 7159 and 4627

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm really sorry for bothering you. It turned out that I missed `JsonExtensionData` attribute. So the `Input` type should look like this:

```
class Input {
  [JsonConverter(typeof(......))]
  public InputType Type {get; set;}

  [JsonExtensionData]
  public IDictionary<string, object> Properties {get; set;}
}
```